# Mysql retrieving range between 2 max values

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to retrieve a range of values between the last row in a table and the row 40 rows above it: 2568, 2567, 2566, etc. The query I'm using is not getting it done:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE front_weight 
BETWEEN 'MAX(front_weight)-40' AND 'MAX(front_weight)'
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your wording I assume front_weight is unique? If so you can use:

```
SELECT * FROM posts
ORDER BY front_weight DESC LIMIT 40
```

Answer (score 1):

try this one:

```
SELECT * FROM posts 
WHERE front_weight 
order by front_weight desc
limit 40
```

instead of front_weight I suppose you have to use some kind of id column